# Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA, Valid Input but getting javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, validation, spring-data-jpa

**UPDATE**

Found the issue, in the validator:

```
if (refData == null || jdbcTemplate == null) return false;
```

When JPA validation kicks in the `injected JdbcTemplate` is null and I was returning `false`.

TL;DR

A property in a `JPA Entity` is decorated with a custom validation annotation. The `isValid` method returns `true`, but getting:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.example.demo.DemoEntity] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
```

**Long Version**

I have an entity with properties which are actually reference data. For some reason proper JPA associations cannot be used and custom validation is needed:

**The Entity :**

```
public class DemoEntity {
  //
  // ... elided for brevity, satisfies JPA requisities
  //

  //
  // Unable to use @OneToOne here with the Car entity
  //
  @ReferenceCode(referenceDataTable = "car_entity", message = "Car ref is not valid")
  private String carCode;
}
```

**Custom Annotation**

```
  @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Constraint(validatedBy = RefDataValidator.class)
  public @interface ReferenceCode {
    String message() default "Not Valid!!!";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    /**
     * The reference table 
     */
    String referenceDataTable();

    /**
     * The column to check for existence 
     */
    String column() default "code";    
  }
```

**Custom Validator**

```
    @Component
    public class RefDataValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ReferenceCode, String> {

    private String tableName;
    private String columnName;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public RefDataValidator() {}

    @Override
    public void initialize(ReferenceCode referenceCode) {
        tableName = referenceCode.referenceDataTable();
        columnName = referenceCode.column();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String refData, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (refData == null || jdbcTemplate == null) return false;

        String query =
                new StringBuilder("select exists(select 1 from ")
                    .append(tableName)
                    .append(" where ")
                    .append(columnName)
                    .append(" = ?)")
                    .toString();

        int exists = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] { refData }, Integer.class);

        boolean ret = (refData != null && exists > 0);
        System.out.println("query: " + query + ", refData: " + refData +   ", returning: " + ret);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/add3")
    public @ResponseBody String addNewUser3(@Valid @RequestBody DemoEntity demo)
    {
        demoRepository.save(demo);
        return "Saved";
    }
```

**Exception Handler**

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class DemoExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    // @Validate For Validating Path Variables and Request Parameters
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public void constraintViolationException(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    }

    // error handle for @Valid
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object>
    handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                 HttpHeaders headers,
                                 HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        body.put("timestamp", new Date());
        body.put("status", status.value());

        //Get all fields errors
        List<String> errors = ex.getBindingResult()
                .getFieldErrors()
                .stream()
                .map(x -> x.getDefaultMessage())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        body.put("errors", errors);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, status);
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface DemoRepository extends CrudRepository<DemoEntity, Integer>{

}
```

Using the following `curl`:

```
curl -d '{"carCode": "t"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -o -X POST http://localhost:8080/demo/add3
```

console window says:

```
query: select exists(select 1 from car_entity where code = ?), refData: t, returning: true
```

Then this error:

```
    2019-12-23 12:06:58.660 ERROR 4532 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction] with root cause

javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.example.demo.DemoEntity] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Car ref is not valid', propertyPath=carCode, rootBeanClass=class com.example.demo.DemoEntity, messageTemplate='Car ref is not valid'}      
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
    ...
```

The custom validator is never called around JPA persist since there is no console.log. I have a feeling it has to do with the `groups` but couldn't figure. Another thing, is mixing `JdbcTemplate` with JPA a bad idea?